# When to use " " ( space ) and when to use . ( dot ) when invoking methods in Scala?

Tags: scala, syntax, language-design

I've seen Scala using both interchangeably, but I don't know when to use one or the other.

Is there a convention?

For instance these are equivalent

```
"hello" toString
```

and

```
"hello".toString()
```

And they can even be mixed

```
"hello".toString() length
```

What's the convention?

Comment: check out http://www.codecommit.com/scala-style-guide.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand on the comment from Yardena, there is an Scala [unofficial style guide](http://www.codecommit.com/scala-style-guide.pdf). It has some suggestions on when to use the dot notation and when to drop the dot and the parenthesis and usually provides a brief rationale for the recommendation, that you may or may not agree with, but at least that's a starting point.

For instance `name toList` may behave differently depending on what's on the next line.

Personally, I would write `hello.toString.length` with the assumption that all calls are side-effect free (so I drop the parenthesis) and then I have to keep the dot for it to compile.

Answer (score 10):

The space convention is generally used when the method functions like an operator (`+`, `*`, etc.); the dot convention is used when it functions more like, well, a method call.

(I know that explanation is kind of vague, but there's not really a hard and fast rule for the usage.)

Comment: I see what you mean. One good example I saw in Coursera's course was with `union` method. I think it looks more readable when written `a union b` using space notation. And this case `union` acts as an operator.